# In spacy, Is it possible to get the corresponding rule id in a match of matches

Tags: nlp, matcher, spacy

In Spacy 2.x, I use the matcher to find specific tokens in my text corpus. Each rule has an ID (`'class-1_0'` for example). During parse, I use the callback `on_match` to handle each match. Is there a solution to retrieve the rule used to find the match directly in the callback.

Here is my sample code.

```
txt = ("Aujourd'hui, je vais me faire une tartine au beurre "
       "de cacahuète, c'est un pilier de ma nourriture "
       "quotidienne.")

nlp = spacy.load('fr')

def on_match(matcher, doc, id, matches):
    span = doc[matches[id][1]:matches[id][2]]
    print(span)
    # find a way to get the corresponding rule without fuzz

matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
matcher.add('class-1_0', on_match, [{'LEMMA': 'pilier'}])
matcher.add('class-1_1', on_match, [{'LEMMA': 'beurre'}, {'LEMMA': 'de'}, {'LEMMA': 'cacahuète'}])

doc = nlp(txt)
matches = matcher(doc)
```

In this case `matches` return :

```
[(12071893341338447867, 9, 12), (4566231695725171773, 16, 17)]
```

`12071893341338447867` is a unique ID based on `class-1_0`. I cannot find the original rule name, even if I do some introspection in `matcher._patterns`.

It would be great if someone can help me.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 12):

Yes – you can simply look up the ID in the `StringStore` of your vocabulary, available via `nlp.vocab.strings` or `doc.vocab.strings`. Going via the `Doc` is pretty convenient here, because you can do so within your `on_match` callback:

```py
def on_match(matcher, doc, match_id, matches):
   string_id = doc.vocab.strings[match_id]
```

For efficiency, spaCy encodes all strings to integers and keeps a reference to the mapping in the `StringStore` lookup table. In spaCy v2.0, the integers are hash values, so they'll always match across models and vocabularies. Fore more details on this, see [this section in the docs](https://spacy.io/usage/spacy-101#vocab).

Of course, if your classes and IDs are kinda cryptic anyways, the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47493898/6400719) suggesting integer IDs will work fine, too. Just keep in mind that those integer IDs you choose will likely also be mapped to some random string in the `StringStore` (like a word, or a part-of-speech tag or something). This usually doesn't matter if you're not looking them up and resolving them to strings somewhere – but if you do, the output may be confusing. For example, if your matcher rule ID is `99` and you're calling `doc.vocab.strings[99]`, this will return `'VERB'`.

Comment: Thank you. I tested your answer, it points to the right direction. But to get the string ID you need to use the integer encoded match rule, not `match_id`.
`string_id = doc.vocab.strings[matches[id][0]]`

Thanks again.

Comment: And thanks for your incredible achievement with spacy 2.0 :)

Answer (score 2):

While writing my question, as often, I found the solution.

It's dead simple, instead of using unicode rule id, like `class-1_0`, simply use a interger. The identifier will be preserved throughout the process.

```
matcher.add(1, on_match, [{'LEMMA': 'pilier'}])
```

Match with

```
[(1, 16, 17),]
```